# ACF overrides HTML attributes added with load_value hook

Tags: html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I'm using ACF together with the ACF Hook [acf/load_value](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_value/) to add a custom HTML wrapper to the ACF value. I use then the ACFs to build an Elementor template (I'm using Elementor PRO).
The Template works and the values of ACFs are rendered, but the attribute I've added in the wrapper disappear

I've tried to change the priority of my filters, but it wasn't the problem. I 've also tried to look into the ACF settings, but seems that I cannot change this behavior just changing some settings.

This is the filter I made

```
if (!function_exists('my_acf_span_property')) {
    function my_acf_span_property($value, $property) {
        $value = '<span property="' . $property . '">' . $value . '</span>';
        return $value;
    }
}

if (!function_exists('my_acf_industry_value')) {
    function my_acf_industry_value($value)
    {
        return my_acf_span_property($value, 'industry');
    }
}

add_filter('acf/format_value/name=industry', 'my_acf_industry_value');
```

I made one filter for each ACF I need to change, this is only one as example.

I've tried to debug the filter changing `return $value;` to `return htmlentities($value);` in the function `my_acf_span_property` and the attributes are rendered in the frontend.

The output was expected to be `<span property="industry">ACF value</span>`
But wat is rendered is `<span>ACF value</span>`

It could be an Elementor problem?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with an action to allow the attributes in the posts

```
if (!function_exists('allow_property_attribute')) {
    function allow_property_attribute() {
        global $allowedposttags, $allowedtags;
        $newattribute = "property";

        $allowedposttags["span"][$newattribute] = true;
        $allowedtags["span"][$newattribute] = true;
        $allowedposttags["div"][$newattribute] = true;
        $allowedtags["div"][$newattribute] = true;
        $allowedposttags["p"][$newattribute] = true;
        $allowedtags["p"][$newattribute] = true;

    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'allow_property_attribute' );
```

It looks like was WordPress my problem, and not Elementor or ACF.